# why segmentation fault when copying memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm running ubuntu on x86_32...and I keep getting segmentation fault while running this program.

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>
char *memcp(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{

    char *dp = dest;
    const char *sp = src;
    while(n--)
        *dp++ = *sp++;
    return dest;

}

int main()
{

    char *s = "abcde";
    char *d;
    char *r = memcp(d,s,6);
    printf("%s",r);

    return(0);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it is running on my friend's x86_64 machine on windows as well as ubuntu. Please help me out ..

Comment: @user583878: You are writing to a not initailized pointer, man. *dp++; is you a writing to random memory location some data. Sometimes it is cause SF, sometimes are not, it dependt whether it is passed the currently allocated segment for the program or not! – Artur Mustafin

Comment: @user583878: All NOT INITIALIZED POINTERS still intialized (stack allocated, if not optimized completely - whiped out if not used), so if I later corrups somehow the stack state, (by calling dll exported function, i.e.), i can later on use this pointer in some useful and meaningful way ;), by the way, look onto your code! you are doing the same, so i'm still right about incorrect USAGE of not initialized pointers )))

Comment: @Artur: That is horrible advice, you should *never* **ever** rely on undefined behaviour even if it *appears* to be working. If you do this, you are drastically reducing the portability and reliability of your code. The compiler does not have to guarantee anything at all when it comes to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @dreamalax: I have not given an ADVICE here, you know. Plese tell me, why do you think I'm advertising such a dubious things? I just said that *I* can use it (not author of the post) in a menigful name, for example in coulpls with __asm, __emb, __declaspec(noalias), __declsec(naked) (using VC++), so, I just disagree with you in point that of your classification, but as I sad, it is a bad practice to use unintialised pointers, whilst you actually can. I didn't, so you should be cereful when using such acclaims, man. That's not smart, actually

Comment: Really, anyone can use uninitalised pointers,... *but only in the way interpret it not only as ponter itsels, but a memory location* If you are not initialized pointer, but allocates some stack for that pointer, why shouldn't you use this space despite the fact that it was declared in C/C++ as a pointer, but *you are smarter than someone else* and use it as a memory location (not as reference to anlother memeory location)?

Answer (score 7):

There's at least two ways to do this:

`malloc` method:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s = "abcde";
    char *d = malloc(6);
    char *r = memcp(d, s, 6);
    printf("%s",r);

    free(d);
    return(0);
}
```

Array method:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s = "abcde";
    char d[6];
    memcp(d, s, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is generally not a good idea to hard code buffer lengths into your code (for example, you are hardcoding 6). If the size of your input changes and you forget to update the number 6, problems will occur.

The reason why you are getting a segmentation fault is because the pointer `d` does not point to anywhere. In your `memcp` function, you are trying to write this pointer but because it does not point anywhere meaningful your program crashes. In the C standard, this is called *undefined behaviour*, and basically it means anything can happen.

Also, it may interest you that there are already two functions available in the Standard C Library, [`memmove`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memmove.html) and [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html). `memmove` is useful if the source and destination areas overlap. If you know they won't ever overlap, `memcpy` may be faster.

Lastly I would like to point out that you should not take the advice from Artur regarding uninitialised pointer usage. You should never rely on the value of an uninitialised pointer and doing so means your program's behaviour is *not* well-defined. Annex J of the C language specification mentions the following that is **undefined behaviour**:

> ### J.2 Undefined Behaviour
>
> 1. The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
>    - …
>    - The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate.
>    - …

Comment: it is generally not a good idea to hard code buffer lengths, agreed, so use dynamic allocation, as you showed up earlier

Comment: yes this code is working fine and you have explained the behaviour correctly...many many thanks.

Comment: @dreamlax: You have a wrong explanation, still ;) It is nonsene that "pointer d does not point to anywhere", it is a poiter, remember? Think twice before post ;) If d is a pointer, anyway, it is a memory location (initialized to zero or not, depends on a system), referenced as a "pointer", so it used as a pointer to memory location, if segment, which pointer d points to is out of scope, SF will raise by the CPU. Think smart, by the way.

Comment: @Artur, it does not point to anywhere, because `d` is not initialized, which means it points to garbage/random. garbage is not acceptable.

Comment: @Artur Mustafin: *"it does not point to anywhere"* in this context should be read as *"it is not defined to point to anywhere in particular"*.

Comment: @Artur: You are thinking on an implementation level. The C language specification does not mention data segments and CPU-level exceptions, it defines behaviour. Also, you are misinterpreting what I am saying; on an implementation-level `d` points to nowhere reliably practicable or useful. As far as the C language specification is concerned, it is simply undefined behaviour.

Comment: It is a pointer, and you do not understan the nature of pinter in C, though. Pointer is an interpretation of a memory location, (4 bytes), so whether it initialized OR not, it is still points to SOMEWERE. ok, see: char* d= 0; // s IS a sponter, and points to memoty location 0x000000 on a x86 system. Do you understand this or not?

Comment: @dreamalax, theoretically, i can agree, but what do you mean under "reliably practicable or useful" ? So, if can force some "not initalized" pointer to points to my data strutures array in some cases (occasionally, i.e.), passing via pointer into some function, and than occasionally work with it in correct manner, does that means that pointer points to something "reliably practiceable and useful" or not?

Comment: @Artur: The only correct way to work with an uninitialised pointer is to initialise it or assign to it from an existing valid pointer of a compatible type. There is no other way to reliably use an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: @dreamalax, @caf: Agreed, but still you can not understand C without underlying understanding of how this "C" language layer works (wrapping to an assembly language). By the way, you can use pure assembly in C programs, [http://byteworm.com/] and that is legal and in "C" standarts, and you CAN use unintialised pointers with assembly inserts, and it will meaning on stack allocation, and also it will be very useful and reliable ;) Moreover, sometimes, this is the only way to code effectively (see SSE4.2 crc32 implementation in a ulr above)! Think about it.

Comment: @Artur: That is not standard C at all. Computed `goto` is a GNU C language extension. Also, you keep insisting on explaining implementation details. C is a hardware-agnostic programming language described in terms of an Abstract Machine. It does not have a concept of a stack or a heap, and it does not have SSE. As far as the C language is specified, if you try to access the value of an uninitialised pointer, it is **undefined behaviour**, and is strictly non-portable and non-conforming.

Comment: @Artur: Also, you can completely understand C without understanding the underlying architecture; C provides a common abstraction amongst popular hardware architectures, but it is not specific to any one of them.

Comment: @dreamlax: You just cant stop, isn't it? You are introducing more and more terms in dialogue, but it is perfectly clear to me that you do not understand what are you talking about, except just confusing the readers. Generally, almost all in computer science can be expressed in terms of abstract machine. All hardware and all software can be described as an abstract machine, abstract state machine, in particualr, the Turing machine. I'm stil thinking that all you do is trying to confuse me or other reader, but you can't,actually. At second, if asm is a keyword, don't you think it IS in standart?

Comment: @Artur: Are you familiar at all with the C language specification? The `asm` keyword is described as being a common extension but it **is not** part of the standard. Also, I keep adding more and more terms because you don't seem to understand that YOU DO NOT USE UNINITIALISED POINTERS. You cannot argue this because even if you think you have found some way to "trick" the compiler into utilising uninitialised values, it is STILL **undefined behaviour** (and not to mention is a useless premature optimisation).