# Difference between `cout << x` and `cout.operator <<(x)`?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to use for_each to print a vector of strings to cout. However, when formulating the statement I found that `std::ostream::operator<<(const std::string &);` is not defined leading to compiler errors. The following code illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string message = "Hello World!\n";

    // This works
    std::cout << message;

    // Compiler error
    std::cout.operator <<(message);
}
```

I thought that both statements should appear identical to the compiler. Apparently they are not. So what is the difference then?

#### Solved

As Tomalak and Prasoon indicated I needed to call this function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::string&);
```

So the following sample will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string message = "Hello World!\n";
    operator<<(std::cout, message);
}
```

Concerning my original goal (to use for_each to print a vector of strings): It seems like it's better to use `std::copy` with `std::ostream_iterator` as illustrated here: [How do I use for_each to output to cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153110/how-do-i-use-for-each-to-output-to-cout)

Comment: did you try to compile my code? I think it will be fun if you choose my answer correct ;) Cheers!

Comment: You question is incorrect, the function you mentioned in code does not exists, so it will never compile. You are calling different fountion operator, that in first <<, so it is not compile, because no such a friend function, nor std << overloadable operator accepting your arguments...

Comment: The most fun is that the right answer is not marked as correct ;) Propbably , i will mark it ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::string&);`. It's a free function.

Comment: +1 for being correct. In particular, for not stating that `std::cout << message` would be equivalent to any particular syntactic form of function call (which is too much of a simplification to be true. What if you have a `operator<<` declared locally? It will hide the non-local name!).

Comment: @Johannes : `What if you have a operator<< declared locally? It will hide the non-local name!)` Considering the given code in the opening post that(quote) seems unlikely.

Comment: @Artur: Since your answer has had 4 downvotes, not sure where you get off downvoting my accepted answer, which otherwise has none! What's incomplete about it?

Comment: @Prasoon true. But there's danger that @Stacked doesn't know about that. If I were him, I would think that they are equivalent when someone tells me "std::cout << message; would be equivalent to operator << (std::cout, message)".

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: Don't worry I'm in no immediate danger :)

Comment: @Tomalak: I think Artur is a troll; he's trying to justify using undefined behaviour in his comments in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4754884/10320).

Comment: @Tomalak: lol, anyway to restore the balance of the universe I have given you an upvote.

Answer (score 13):

`std::cout << message;` would be equivalent to `operator << (std::cout, message)` not what you've written.

[operator `<<`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) has been defined as a free function and not as a member function

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::string& s) { ... }`