# Difference between `cout << x` and `cout.operator<<(x)` and `operator(std::cout, x)`?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cout

This is related to the [difference-between-cout-x-and-cout-operator-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763067/difference-between-cout-x-and-cout-operator-x) question, but still a little different...

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

    std::cout.operator<<("hello2");
    std::cout.operator<<(std::endl);

    operator<<(std::cout, "hello3");
//    operator<<(std::cout, std::endl);

    return 0;
}
```

### Q1: Why does `std::cout.operator<<("hello2");` work?

From [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763067/difference-between-cout-x-and-cout-operator-x) on SO I would expect the compiler to complain since `operator<<` is meant to be a free function and not a member of `cout`. On my system, however, it prints "0x10d54df31". And, stranger yet, the following line correctly correctly executes `std::endl`.

### Q2: Why does `operator<<(std::cout, std::endl);` not work?

I know that `std::endl` is a function, but it seems strange (to me) that the hello3 output works whilst the `std::endl' doesn't. Instead the compiler throws an error:

```
main.cpp:10:4: error: no matching function for call to 'operator<<'
    operator<<(std::cout, std::endl);
```

### Q3: How can the first `std::cout << "hello1" << std::endl;` be written in `operator<<(...)` form?

If the first two questions have been answered, then this has probably already covered. It's the point of this learning exercise, so seems sensible to ask it explicitly.

Comment: This sounds very much like **homework**, questions that couldn't very well be posed without knowing the answers.

Comment: @Alf definitely not part of my homework! Glad to hear that my questions sound well informed, though :)

Comment: @Jerry could you tell me what editing changes you made, please? I'll try improve the format of future questions...

Comment: @GnomeDePlume: If you click on the "edited N mins ago" it'll show you a diff. In this case it was mostly just some mis-matched quotes. Looking at it again, however, my last edit (changing "is" to "has") was clearly a mistake. I think I intended to change it to "was".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators can be implemented in different ways, in particular an `operator<<` for which the left hand side is your type can be implemented as either a free function or as a member function of that left hand side type.

While you must implement `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, MyType const&)` as a free function (since `MyType` is not the left hand side), the library implementation can choose<sup>*</sup> to implement `operator<<` for some fundamental types insde the `std::ostream` type (which is really a particular instantiation of a template, I am trying to ignore the details).

Edit: After checking with the standard this is incorrect:

<strike>This is what you are noticing in the code, the overload that takes a `const char*` is implemented as a member of `ostream` (`basic_ostream<char,char_traits<char>`).</strike>

The overloads taking manipulators are implemented as member functions (Q2), and there is an implicit conversion from `const char*` to `const void*` that will be picked if you use the syntax for explicitly calling a member operator (Q1). For Q3, the answer would be:

```
operator<<(std::cout, "Hello").operator<<(std::endl);
```

<sup>*</sup> The implementation is actually not *free* to choose, since the standard mandates the signatures.

Comment: Let's see if I understand this... The use of `operator<<` with `std::endl` (a manipulator) is implemented as a member function of `cout` (or other similar object). So that line works.

Comment: However, the use of `operator<<` with a fundamental type is not (necessarily) implemented as a member function...

Comment: Correct, you can take a look at the declaration of `basic_ostream` in any of the C++ standard drafts to get the list (27.7.3.1)

Comment: I still don't understand why  `operator<<` must always be used as a free function if used with a user-defined type (`MyType`), though... If the free function can handle arbitrary user types, why not the member functions of `std::ostream` (such as `cout`)?

Comment: @GnomeDePlume: operators can be implemented as member functions *only* on the class that is the left-hand-side, not the right hand side. To be able to implement `operator<<` for `MyType` as a member in `std::basic_ostream` you would need to modify the definition of `std::basic_ostream`, but that is provided by the implementation and cannot be modified.

Comment: Got'ya. Okay, possibly the last sub-question: the conversion from `const char*` to `const void*` is done to convert the argument (in this case `"hello2"` into a form that `std::cout.operator` can handle. So it takes my *pointer-to-a-character* and turns it into a *pointer-to-a-function-returning-void*. Is the output that it prints the function address for that (non-existent) void function?

Comment: no, there's no function thing involved. it's just a pointer to `void`. because that's the formal argument type.

Comment: @GnomeDePlume: There is no pointer to function, just pointer to `void`, that is an *address*, which in this case will be the address of the first character in the C-style string.

Comment: Okay. [void represents the absence of type](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/#void_pointers) (I'm learning about all *types* of things today. It makes sense that the address is output, since the compiler cannot know what data type  is stored in memory at that position...

Answer (score 1):

Some overloads of `operator<<` are class members, others are not.

In C++03 this created some baffling call scenarios since a reference to non-`const` (argument of the not-member) can't be bound to an rvalue, but in C++11 at least one such has been fixed by introducing an rvalue reference argument overload.

So, which calls compile or not depends more in general also on the C++ standards version, C++03 or C++11.

Comment: I tried compiling (g++) with with '-std=c++11' but it made no difference to the calls in the test program. Useful to know, though!

Comment: @GnomeDePlume: at the moment Codepad is one pastebin that uses a pretty old compiler. so you can look at the example at (http://codepad.org/h7WXNhuW). unfortunately that code compiles without error when I specify `-std=c++03` to MinGW g++ 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of member output operators defined in `std::ostream`. In retrospect that was probably an error but when IOStreams were first created I think it was actually necessary. These member operators include the overloads taking function pointers which means you'll need to use member notation for those. The operators using C-strings are non-member overloads, i.e., you need to use the non-member function call notation to get the C-string overload. When you call the member operator with a `char const*` the `char const*` will be converted to `void const*` for which there is a member output operator.

Comment: That conversion from `char const*` to `void const*` sounds nasty. Is there a reason for it, or is just another casualty of [explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean) not being the default?

Comment: @GnomeDePlume: Well, the best match for `out.operator<< (str)` for an `std::ostream& out` and a `char const* str` is the overload `std::ostream::operator<< (void const*)` and this is, thus, chosen. When using operator call notation `std::operator<< (std::ostream&, char const*)` is a better match.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions can be broken down to member functions an non-member functions.

Having 13.5.2 Binary operators

> A binary operator shall be implemented
>   either by a non-static member function (9.3) with one parameter or by
>   a non-member function with two parameters. Thus, for any binary
>   operator @, x@y can be interpreted as either x.operator@(y) or
>   operator@(x,y). If both forms of the operator function have been
>   declared, the rules in 13.3.1.2 determine which, if  any,
>   interpretation is used.

Omitting a quote of 13.3.1.2 the member function (operator) is preferred.

The line 'std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;' involves non member functions. Each 'std::cout.operator' is an explicit member function call.

- Q1 is the member operator<<(const void*)
- Q2 there is no member taking a function
- Q3 It is not possible