# Why there is a segmentation fault in this case?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why segmentation fault in this program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754884/why-segmentation-fault-in-this-program)

```
int main()
{
        char *a="asdasd";
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
                (*a)++;
                printf("\n%s",a);

        }
}
```

Output Segmentation fault

```
int main()
{
        char a[]="asdasd";
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
                (*a)++;
                printf("\n%s",a);

        }
}
```

No segmentation fault

Comment: Segmentation fault in the first program because you were lucky. No segmentation fault in the 2nd program because you were unlucky. Calling `printf()` (or any function accepting a variable number of parameters) without a prototype in scope invokes Undefined Behaviour. One of the manifestations of Undefined Behaviour is a segmentation fault (a good manifestation); another is everything working as you expect (a bad manifestation) ... Oh, and you're trying to change a non modifiable array in the first program too: another case of Undefined Behaviour

Comment: @pmg Can you provide some links about the manifestations of Undefined Behaviour?

Comment: @bacchus: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior

Comment: Can I say that when i declare char a[] = "asdasd" the pointer to array a is constant pointer or in exact sense decays to constant pointer but when i declare char *a="sadasd" it is a variable pointer to char but the string is a constant. Is there a way to modify this string?

Comment: Could you point me some good source where i can get all this stuff cleared?

Comment: what prototype should i define ?? sorry i dinnt get what you mean

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, you're declaring a pointer to `char` and assigning the value of a pointer to a constant `char` to in. In the second one, you're declaring an array of `char` and giving it it an initial value, but it ends up to not be a constant. In the loop, you try to increment the value at the location of the pointer or the first index of the array. Since the pointer one points to a constant `char`, it fails: you can't change a constant. The array, however, can be modified, and therefore, does not fail.

Comment: In C string literals (of type `char[]`) decay to `char*`, not `const char*` as your answer suggests. I think it is a good idea to add `const` to the pointer (`const char *a = "foo";`) but that is irrelevant to the issue

Comment: But isn't icktoofay's point that the string literal is 'constant' (i.e. non-modifiable) - it's not about 'const' the keyword.

Comment: @pmg: I'm sorry, I was trying to say that the array was modifiable, but the one defined as a `char *` but assigned with a `const char *` value wasn't. Perhaps I wasn't as clear as I could have been.

Comment: In C, "foobar" is of type `char[7]` (Standard 6.4.5/5), I believe in C++ the same string literal if of type `const char[7]`. In C some implementations may allow changes to such arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture you're using implements `char *a="asdasd";` by storing the constant string `"asdasd"` in pages that are marked read-only because it *really* is `const char*` even though you said otherwise. This is a good thing because it makes it easier for your operating system to share these pages across multiple processes (like it can do with code).

If you're using gcc you can use `-Wwrite-strings` to have the compiler warn you when you do this, or if you're using an [older version](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html) (pre-4.0), `-fwritable-strings` (or `-traditional`) to not use the read-only page mapping.

Comment: Hmm .. in C string literals are `char[]`, not `const char[]` or `const char*`. Using `gcc -Wwrite-strings` makes gcc a compiler implementation for a language similar to C, but not quite C.

Comment: @pmg String literals have formal type `char []` but semantic type `const char []`. C++ changed it with their last iteration, C compilers are bound to follow.